# Attempting to write data to file

Tags: c, file-io

I'm attempting to get user input to be written to a file so that it can be sent over wifi. I've followed some tutorials and from what I gather this seems to be the appropriate way to approach writing data to a file. Unfortunately it seems that, while the program can identify the information that I want written, it does not write it to a file nor even create the file itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 120

int main(){

char *cArray[MAX_STR_LEN] = { "example", "dinosaurs" };
char cInput[MAX_STR_LEN] = { 0 };
int y = 0;
FILE *pWrite;

printf("Type your message:\n");
fgets(cInput, MAX_STR_LEN, stdin);
cInput[strlen(cInput) - 1] = 0;     /* strip newline from input */
printf("\nInitialised string array:\n");

while (cArray[y]){
    char * ptr = cInput;
    while ((ptr = strstr(ptr, cArray[y])) != NULL){
        char *ep = strchr (ptr, ' ');
        if (ep) *ep = 0;              /* null-terminate at space */
        printf("%s\n", ptr++);
        pWrite = fopen("test.txt", "a");
        if ( pWrite != NULL ) {
            fprintf(pWrite, "%s\n", ptr);
            fclose(pWrite);
        } else {
            goto ErrorHandler; //there is a file i/o error
        }
        if (ep) *ep = ' ';            /* put the space back      */
    }
    y++;
    }
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;

time ( &rawtime );
timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
printf ( "Timestamp: %s", asctime (timeinfo) );

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); //exit program normally

ErrorHandler:
perror("The following error occurred");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //exit program with error
}
```

Output:

```
Type your message:
this is an example

Initialised string array:
example
Timestamp: Sat Mar  7 12:20:02 2015
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I'm still very new at this so any and all feedback would be greatly appreciated. Similarly, if anyone has a vague understanding of the Multipeer Connectivity Framework for OSX and could direct me to a resource, that would be fantastic.

Comment: In your code you increase `ptr` twice and I think this is your problem : 1. `printf("%s\n", ptr++);` and 2. `fprintf(pWrite, "%s\n", ptr++);`

Comment: Ok I edited that part out though I'm still stuck. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I try it in my computer and it's work well, it writes "xample" in test.txt and if you changed `printf("%s\n", ptr++);` into `printf("%s\n", ptr);` and instead changed `fprintf(pWrite, "%s\n", ptr);` into `fprintf(pWrite, "%s\n", ptr++);` it write example in test.txt.

Comment: What is the directory of test.txt for you because I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Never mind! I added `char * dir = getcwd(NULL, 0);
printf("Current dir: %s", dir);` to the code and found out that the cwd was actually buried deep in my user directory. I'll figure out how to change that to something more accessible but until then this program works! Thank you very much!